# Babel arrow function compilation into ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=FAYw9gdgzgLgBAQwA5LgXjgCgJToHxwDeAvkA) I've noticed something a little weird.

Shouldn't `const app = () => {}` be equal to `var app = function() {}`
?

Babel returns `var app = function app() {}`.

Comment: No, babel is correct as an arrow function assigned to a var should in theory have a name property equivalent to the name of that var to assist in stack traces. Check out [this](http://2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html) link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, babel is correct as an arrow function assigned to a var should in theory have a name property equivalent to the name of that var to assist in stack traces and reflection. Check out [this](http://2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html) link for more info. Quick summary in case it goes stale:

The name property of a function is created at declaration time. The name property of a function expression is inferred from the name binding:

```
var foo = function() {};
console.log(foo.name); // foo
```

Arrow functions have the same behavior:

```
var foo = () => {};
console.log(foo.name); // foo
```

Since this didn't actually get standardized until ES 2015/ES 6 babel has to actually add the name to create a [*named* function expression](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/):

```
var foo = function foo() {}; // notice it's function *foo* now
```

to support legacy environments.